# What am I Doing Wrong with IQueryable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable, iqueryable

I thought IQueryable`<T>` was derrived from IEnumerable`<T>`, so why can't I access the results of my query like a collection of records?

```
public bool DoLogIn(System.String strUserName, System.String strPassword)
{
    if (this.IsLoggedIn)
        return false;

    ASRDBDataContext ASRData = new ASRDBDataContext();
    IQueryable<user> CurrUser =
        from usr in ASRData.users
        where usr.userName == strUserName
        where usr.password == strPassword
        select usr;

    if (CurrUser.Count() != 1)
        return false;

    this.CurrUserID = CurrUser[0].userID;   // Error
    return true;
}
```

The error returned is: "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`<user>`'"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IEnumerable is not indexable. Neither is IQueryable.

If you want the first item of a LINQ query, try using the [First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.first.aspx), [FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.firstordefault.aspx), [Single()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.single.aspx), or [SingleOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.singleordefault.aspx) methods.